# sqlalchemy searching for multiple ( unknown mumber) keywords

Tags: sqlalchemy, keyword, chaining

In SQLAlchemy, for example, I'd like to search for keywords "foo", "bar" and possibly but not necessarily more keywords in the "description" column of my Item class, so I build a list of such keywords:
["foo", "bar"],

and then use primitive looping to achieve my goal:

```
query_obj = session.query(Item)
for k in search_keywords:
query_obj = query_obj.filter(Item.description.like('%{0}%'.format(k)))
```

but this doesn't seem very elegant. I think there could be a better solution in sqlalchemy. Could someone share some tips other than looping and chaining? Thanks.

p.s. Also what is the best practice to achieve a "OR" search of multiple(indefinite number of) keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your code is as elegant as it gets, I do not think you can improve it significantly.*

In order to solve the same for `OR`, you can collect the clauses into a list first, and then apply `or_` with the `filter(...)`:

```
q = session.query(Item)
clauses = [Item.description.like('%{0}%'.format(k)) for k in search_keywords]
q = q.filter(or_(*clauses))
```

If you find it more elegant, you can use it for `AND` case you have as well by calling `and_` instead of `or_`.